# How do i solve my error to run flutter app

Tags: flutter

I face error when running my flutter app:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Pixel 4 in debug mode..
Built build\app\outputs \flutter -apk\app-debug.apk.
E/flutter (11426): [ERROR: flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(144)] Could not prepare isolate.
E/flutter (11426): [ERROR: flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(422)] Could not create root isolate.
E/flutter (11426): [ERROR: flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(614)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
```

I’ve tried uninstalling flutter and installing back, i’ve tried reinstalling the git

Comment: First run 'flutter doctor' in terminal then you will get all the issues related to flutter installation

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for a variety of reasons, but some common causes include:

Missing or **corrupt Flutter SDK** or having incorrect Flutter configuration.

Have you tried **Reinstalling Flutter**?

Comment: yes i have tried reinstalling flutter